# How to validate array values in Laravel request class?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request, validationmessage

In my application I have a request file as below:

**storeFactoryUser.php**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'factory_users' => 'array',
            'factory_users.*.first_name' => 'required',
            'factory_users.*.last_name' => 'required',
            'factory_users.*.username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users,username',
            'factory_users.*.f_user_email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
            'factory_users.*.external_ref' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

Now when I enter a username that already exists, it returns an error message as below:

```
The factory_users.1.username has already been taken.
```

Instead of displaying it as above, I need to display it with the array value, for example:

```
Given factory user's username factory1 has already been taken.
```

To achieve this, I wrote a message function as below:

```
public function messages()
{
    $messages = [];
    foreach ($this->factory_users as $key => $factory_user) {
        $messages['factory_users.*.username.alpha_dash|unique:users,username'] = "Given factory user's username ".$factory_user['username'].' has already been taken.';
    }

    return $messages;
}
```

But still, it returns the same error message which I've mentioned above.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925592/laravel-custom-messages-for-array-validation

Comment: yes, but it didn't help me. I would be much pleased if you could provide me an example :)

Comment: public function messages()
{
    return [
        'factory_users.*.f_user_email.unique' => 'Given factory user's username XYZ has already been taken.',
    ];
} //Try this one and let me know

Comment: The factory_users.0.username has already been taken this is the response, it's not showing the message inside messages function :/

Comment: Are you sure that your array key is 'f_user_email' ? show me your message function

Comment: I've updated my question, please check

Comment: Try without for loop and with static testing message like this return [
  'factory_users.*.username.unique' => "username already been taken.",
        'factory_users.*.f_user_email.unique' => "email already been taken.",
    ];

Comment: yeah, but I need to display the array values as well, because as this is an array need to show exactly where the error is

Comment: can you just give a chance please?

Comment: okay I'll try and inform you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this..

```
$factory_user['username']
```

instead of

```
$factory_user->username
```

Comment: this solved one of my issues, now Trying to get property 'username' of non-object error is not thrown, but still, it is not displaying the error message inside messages function :/

Comment: I'm glad it helped you fix one of your problem. Will try to find why its not displaying the message. I guess its the message[] not cooked in proper way. notsure though.